# Horizontal Bar across page with different color on each side

Tags: html, css

I need to design something as show below.

So far I have managed to do as http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/1006/ but I am not able to add different color on each side of navigation bar and Image Bar as show in example. I am not sure how to do it.

Help in this regard is appreciated.

[image]

Sample code

```
<div id="BannerBar"></div>
<div id="navBar"></div>
<div id="TopImageBar"></div>
<div id="imageBar"></div>
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="logowrapper">LOGO</div>
    <div id="NavigationWrapper">Home | About Us | News | Something</div>
    <div id="TopImageWrapper">IMAGE HERE </div>
</div>
<div id="footerBar"></div>
```

Comment: maybe use before and after onthis bar or inside 2 divs (which is easier and supported not like bfeore on IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's modified jsfiddle for you , on both sides `#navbar` has 2 div `#leftNav` and `#rightNav` with black and red background-color
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/qVtt5/)

second way is to use :before an :after which I do not recommend because IE8 has problem with :before pseudo-element

**EDIT:**

I was thinking about IE7, not IE8 where it work just need to declare `<!DOCTYPE>`.

Comment: I think this should work in IE 8 also... Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/qVtt5/1/

Comment: This on will because you used my way, :before and after should work to with declared <!DOCTYPE>. But anyway I feel more secure with my way. In a matter of fact it depends on you which way you use.

Comment: I need this to be supported by atleast IE 8 so i will use your first option. I also tried before & after. It also works on IE8. but i am not sure if it will work on actual IE8 as i used F12 option to IE 8 Browser Mode i am not sure how exactly it replicate actual IE8 browser

Comment: I never trust in 100% compatibility mode F12 when I try IE8. That's why I gave you trust and tested way. For me if I might say IE Sux, there's shouldn't be problem with browser like this nowadays. hey should do auto upgrades so noone should use this old crap :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#navBar:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: gray;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
}

#TopImageBar:before {
    background: gray;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Done: http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/1014/

You can update colors from left and right now.

```
.TopImageBar
{
    height: 80px;
    background: blue;
    margin-top:90px;
    width:50%; 
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

.TopImageBar.Right {
     background: red;
     right: 0%;
}
```